# How do I remove a newline from text in vi on Cygwin

Tags: windows, cygwin, vi

I'm trying to ammend a commit comment on a git commit, so I `git commit --amend` then vi opens with text from the last commit's comment. Then I delete all of the text on the first line, but I cannot remove the newline character, how can I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

J - Join two lines

Comment: @Erik: If it has worked, please click on the tick left to the answer.

Comment: I had to wait 2mins ={

Comment: J doesn't seem to work here, my cursor just jumps to the next line

Comment: seems the correct usage is `SHIFT+J`

Answer (score 4):

You can use `dd` to delete the whole current line, whether it is empty or not.